Why would design files produced by a project be called "collateral"?
I've been checking out the Open Compute Project's contributions database which is where you can find a bunch of design files for open-source computing hardware developed by OCP members. Cutting through the hardware nerdery here, it's essentially a place where you can grab specs and design files for stuff like server motherboards.
While chatting about this on Mastodon, a friend wondered why they call the design files "collateral".

(Screenshot of a search result for "Grand Teton" on the OCP website. Captured 2024-08-22.)
This terminology appears in quite a few places on the site, but it's not the only place I've heard the material assets produced by a project be referred to as "collateral". I've heard the same phrasing used elsewhere in the electronics industry, but also in the software and security industries. I just kinda accepted it as a term, and didn't really think about the etymology until now, when I realised I don't know why they call it that either.
My educated guess is that it's a somewhat tortured version of the financial definition, since that usually refers to a valuable asset, but I can't actually find an authoritative source to verify this. Anyone know the actual etymology here?

I have a sneaking suspicion it's because they are collated.

Okay, there is definitely something odd going on with the words collate and collateral,  and it doesn't look like it's confined to AI hallucinations, either. There is a banking software called Collate that manages collateral and might be a source of confusion.

From M-W: "informational materials (such as brochures and fact sheets) used in selling a product or service to a prospective customer or buyer". While there may not be any actual selling going on here, the relationship is similar.

@Barmar It's such a different type of material, though, so I'm not sure that the marketing sense applies. Here we're talking about technical project files for producing a piece of hardware, such as gerber files that tell the PCB manufacturer where all the copper needs to be on the board, NC drill files that tell them where to drill holes, PNP files that tell the assembly system what parts need to go where and in what orientation, etc. along with hundreds of pages of schematics. I've also heard the term used in cases where there's no documentation at all, e.g. just compiled binary files.

Words are often generalized when there's no existing appropriate word. I've often heard "collateral" used to refer to any accompanying material.

This is a bit vague, since it's getting on for 30 years since I was professionally in the EDA space so I can't back it up or formalise it enough to make an answer, but it's the stuff that can be generated from the primary representation that the tool used to create the design works with; so for a PCB you'd have an Eagle file (or whatever people use nowadays) and then the drill fill and the pdf schematics are generated off of that, they aren't the mainline of the design but collateral to it, like a collateral branch of a tree.

@PeteKirkham "The collateral branch of a tree" sounds much closer to a plausible etymological root (I fully embrace this pun) than the marketing definition. And yes, that's exactly the way this works, although in this context the collateral includes the original project files (in this case Cadence Allegro / OrCAD) alongside the production files.
